# When we have persist MEMORY_ONLY option in spark then why we need cache () function? What is the exact difference between these 2 and when to use what

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

cache() method default saves it to memory (MEMORY_ONLY). In persist() method if we define it as persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) it is same as cache(). So then what is the difference between these two? why we need cache() when we can use persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) or vice versa.

Please advice, thanks

Comment: 1. when you use .persist(...) then you need say .unpersist(...).

Comment: From Pyspark 2.1+, `cache` is `persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)`  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache

Answer (score 0):

One is just a handy shortcut for the other, there is no difference. (Infact I believe cache just calls `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)`)